# Resumo de Posts no WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Preciso que o tamanho do resumo dos post na minha frontpage seja diferente do tamanho do resumo da pagina onde é exibido todos os posts(`home.php`).

No meu arquivo `functions.php` eu coloquei o seguinte código:

```
//adiciona um novo tamanho de resumo de posts
function novo_tamanho_do_resumo($length) {
    return 15; //15 palavras
}
add_filter('excerpt_length', 'novo_tamanho_do_resumo');
```

O problema deste código é que o resumo ficou com 15 palavras em todas as páginas, no entanto eu preciso que em `frontpage.php` seja 15 palavras, e que em `home.php` tenha 100 palavras.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para solucionar este problema eu fiz assim:

criei a seguinte função no arquivo functions.php

```
function cropText($texto, $limite){
    if (strlen($texto) <= $limite) echo $texto;
    echo array_shift(explode('||', wordwrap($texto, $limite, '||'))) . " [...]";
}
```

e na minha frontpage.php eu chamo o conteúdo do post e limito os caracteres assim:

```
<?php cropText(get_the_content(), 120); ?>
```

Desta forma o resumo na frontpage terá sempre 120 caracteres enquanto o resumo da pagina de posts continua com o padrão de 55 palavras.

Answer (score 2):

Quando você cria uma action para um determinado hook, dentro desta função podem existir verificações para o que você precisar e retornar o valor de acordo.

No seu caso você pode fazer:

```
//adiciona um novo tamanho de resumo de posts
function novo_tamanho_do_resumo ( $length ) {

    if ( is_frontpage() ) { // ou qualquer outro if pra verificar em qual página está

        return 15; //15 palavras

    } else if ( is_home() ) {

        return 100; //100 palavras

    } else {

        return 55; //valor padrão

    }

}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'novo_tamanho_do_resumo' );
```

Comment: tentei fazer desta forma, porém esta caindo sempre no segundo "if ( is_home() )" ficando em ambas as páginas 100 palavras... meu código esta exatamente como o seu, apenas corrigi a função is_frontpage() para is_front_page(), pois estava dando um erro de função indefinida.